# Friction cause a car to acceleration AND also to stop?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I understand how friction works in order to accelerate a car. The wheels pushes the road back and this causes a reaction force (friction) to push the wheel forward.

My question is how does friction, which acted in the +x direction when accelerating, suddenly switch directions to the -x direction. The wheels are still turning in the same direction as before? How does this work?

Comment: See this previous question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566088/

Comment: That question doesn't really give a satisfactory answer, by Newtowns second law the only way for something to change its velocity is for a net external force acting on it. The acting answer says nothing about forces external to the car only internal which can't cause the car to accelerate.

Comment: Even if the existing answer is not satisfactory, you may add a comment there or, when you'll have enough reputation, you may put a bounty to foster a better answer. Asking an almost equal question may cause it to be closed as a duplicate. In any case, have a look at this site policy about duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is how does friction which acted in the +x direction when accelerating suddenly switch directions to the -x direction. The wheels are still turning in the same direction as before? How does this work?

It is important to recognize that static friction is an unusual force. Most forces have a force law that is an equality. Like Hooke’s law: $F=-kx$. The force has a definite value.

Static friction is not like that. It is given by an inequality: $F\le \mu N$. So the static friction force can assume any direction and any magnitude (less than the maximum) needed to prevent slipping.

When the wheels are powered they tend to slip backwards, so a forward friction force is produced. When the car is braking the wheels tend to slip forward, so a backward friction force is produced.

Answer (score 2):

To accelerate the car, the engine applies a torque to the wheels and the tire friction against the pavement applies a force to the tire surface which points in the direction of the car's travel.

You decelerate the car by putting on the brakes. The brake shoes apply a countertorque to the rotating wheels, and again a friction force is developed but this time that force points in the direction opposite to the car's motion, which therefore decelerates the car.

Answer (score 0):

The direction in which the wheels are turning doesn't determine the direction of the frictional force from the road. Remember that there is almost no relative motion between the bottom of a tyre and the road surface – unless the car is skidding.

It's simple kinematics to show that for no skidding, the car's acceleration, $a$, is related to the angular acceleration, $\alpha$, of its wheels by $a=r \alpha$ in which $r$ is the outer radius of its tyres. So if we stop going faster and apply the brakes instead, $\alpha$ changes sign and so does $a$. Thus (still for no skidding) the force between tyre and road changes sign – even though the wheels are still turning in the same sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, friction is required for the acceleration of a vehicle and also to stop.
First, let us discuss the acceleration of a vehicle. The wheels roll by pushing the ground backward and gets a forward thrust. The friction induces a [frictional torque](https://dewwool.com/angular-friction/). Without friction, this forward motion is not possible. It is similar to our walking, we push the ground to get a forward push.

When we want to stop we need an external force to justify newton's first law of motion. Friction acts as the external force stopping the vehicle. But in this case the applied force in forward direction is removed, there is no push in forward direction. You can visit this [link](https://dewwool.com/friction-is-a-necessary-evil-explain/) for animations.