# Shouldn't acceleration of a car be due to kinetic friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, velocity, free-body-diagram, angular-velocity

During pure rolling when the car is at a constant velocity the velocity of the bottom part of the tire will be 0. But if we push on the gas we apply an angular acceleration on the tire. So now the bottom of the tire will have a net velocity as it has it's linear velocity plus it's angular velocity which is now larger and in the opposite direction. So now there will be a kinetic friction force in the forward direction opposing the backward velocity right?

Comment: When you see cars pull away from a stop, are the tires skidding on the ground or is the bottom of the tire motionless on the road surface?

Comment: That's what I'm also confused about. This answer suggests that they "slip" : https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/609940/331022

Comment: Most tires don't slip much.   Why does your question assume the angular velocity is larger than the linear velocity?  Why couldn't they be equal?

Comment: In that other answer I was not intending to suggest that they slip. I specifically said that the static friction is whatever force is needed to **prevent** slipping. The phrase "tends to slip" was not meant to indicate that it does slip, merely that it is attempting to slip. The static friction force acts to prevent that tendency

Comment: Oh ok, it's making much more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when a car accelerates the tires still retain static friction with the road. It is only if you "peel out" that the tires slip relative to the road and you get kinetic friction.

When you push on the gas you do not apply an angular acceleration, you apply a torque to the axle. This torque at the axle increases the static friction at the contact patch. Remember that the static friction equation is an inequality and the force assumes whatever force is necessary to prevent slipping. This increased static friction force accelerates the car forward and counteracts the torque applied at the axle. This greatly reduces the angular acceleration such that it matches the linear acceleration without slipping.

Comment: So at the bottom of the tire the torque caused by the engine is counteracted by the static friction force (equal magnitude opposite direction). But the tire still has a net angular acceleration in the direction of the torque by the engine to match the linear acceleration caused by the same static friction right? If so where is this angular acceleration coming from?

Comment: @WilliamHarvey It is not quite equal magnitude. As I said it reduces the angular acceleration such that it matches the linear acceleration. It does not reduce it to 0 as you would get with an equal magnitude.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense, but why wouldn't it be equal in magnitude. Should't static friction fully oppose any force as long as the force is smaller than the max force static friction can provide?

Comment: @WilliamHarvey you have to be very careful in your language and thoughts here. There is the force and linear acceleration, and there are the torques and angular acceleration. Static friction means that the angular and linear accelerations must match to avoid slipping. There is no opposing linear force, so it must accelerate linearly. Because it accelerates linearly it must also have the matching angular acceleration. The matching angular acceleration implies that the tire torque cannot be equal in magnitude

Comment: Equal in magnitude to the axle torque